# did not get back date value from column ( mysql )

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE date = curdate() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

It gives back date value from column, but i want last last entry of colum, For example date1, date2, date3. I stored value to date1 and after on date2 i get date1  value but i dident store any value on date2 then i did not get back date value on date3.

Plz help me any one to solve this.

Comment: Add PHP code you're using to query this and access the results

Comment: `order by date desc limit 1`, then...

Comment: If you're just trying to get `DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL 1 Day)` why not do that? Your query shouldn't pull results where none exist...

Comment: i need any back daye value

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column FROM table order by date desc limit 1
```

to get last date colum value.